# What is the wiggle in the AGB branch?

Tags: stellar-evolution, hr-diagram

In many HR diagrams, the asymptotic giant branch includes a wiggle. I thought that these are thermal pulses, but now I realise there are many thermal pulses, and I find only one wiggle. The wiggle could be dredge-ups, but there could be more dredge-ups, as there are way more than one thermal pulses.

What is the wiggle in the AGB phase?

Thermal Pulses:
[image]

Wiggle on a solar mass star's AGB path:
[image]

Wiggle on a 5 solar mass star's AGB path:

[image]

All images from [AGB Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_giant_branch).

Comment: Hi! May you be more precise about what "wiggle" you're referring to? There's many wiggle-like features ;D For example, you could identify it by the stellar stages that precede and follow it.